# Trouble with applying puppetdb module

Tags: puppet

I'm having some trouble setting up the puppetdb module.  When I try to apply the single node manifest that is recommended I get this error:

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install postgresql-9.6' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-9.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.6'
Error: /Stage[main]/Postgresql::Server::Install/Package[postgresql-server]/ensure: change from 'purged' to 'present' failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install postgresql-9.6' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-9.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.6'
```

This is on Ubuntu 18.04.03

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory: you're trying to install `postgresl-9.6`, but there is no such package. Ubuntu 18.04 only has `postgresql-10`.

Comment: By *the* puppetdb module, do you mean [puppetlabs-puppetdb](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb)?  Else, which module do you actually mean?  Either way, what version of the module are you trying to use?

Comment: Yes, the one found at the forge:  https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb.  I was using the most recent version of the module.  I figured out my issue, though.  Since I was installing this on a docker container that didn't contain the Linux lsb-core package, I suspect some script that was trying to write the correct repo to apt sources was getting nothing when calling $(lsb-release).  Basically the file at /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt.postgresql.org.list was getting written over to contain  
"deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ -pgdg main 9.6" and not "bionic-pgdg main 9.6"